# Applying Fragment Shaders on MediaCodec-generated Surface intended for lockCanvas()

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

Most of the code for generating videos using `MediaCodec` I've seen so far either use pure `OpenGL` or locking the Canvas from the *MediaCodec-generated* Surface and editing it. Can I do it with a mix of both?

For example, if I generate my frames in the latter way, is it possible to apply a *Fragment Shader* on the *MediaCodec-generated* Surface before or after editing the Surface's Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

A Surface is the producer end of a producer-consumer pair.  Only one producer can be connected at a time, so you can't use GLES and Canvas on the same Surface without disconnecting one and attaching the other.

Last I checked (Lollipop) there was no way to disconnect a Canvas.  So switching back and forth is not possible.

What you would need to do is:

- Create a [Canvas backed by a Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)).
- Render onto that Canvas.
- Upload the rendered Bitmap to GLES with `glTexImage2D()`.
- Blit the bitmap with GLES, using your desired fragment shader.

The overhead associated with the upload is unavoidable, but remember that you can draw the Bitmap at a smaller resolution and let GLES scale it up.  Because you're drawing on a Bitmap rather than a Surface, it's not necessary to redraw the entire screen for every update, so there is some opportunity to reduce Canvas rendering overhead.

All of the above holds regardless of what the Surface is connected to -- could be MediaCodec, SurfaceView, SurfaceTexture, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one question, though: How do I actually blit the bitmap with GLES? Texture a rectangle with said bitmap and drawing the rectangle on the surface?

Comment: Yup. You can find examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika); just look for uses of FullFrameRect.